# Why did the Nest-builders want to prevent the Shadows from entering our universe?

Tags: alastair-reynolds, revelation-space

In Alastair Reynold's *Absolution Gap* mankind is ultimately saved by the Nest-builder race. The Nest-builders cooperated once asked, yet were unwilling to offer support before.

Dan Sylveste sends the protagonists via Aura to find the Haldora object and to contact the Shadows. It is never directly said, but there are strong indicators that the Shadows are future mankind pushed to the brink of annihilation by Greenfly.

The local Scuttler race attempted to save itself by letting the, at that point purely digitally existing, Shadows back into the past. The Nest-builders wiped them out for that and would have attacked mankind had they attempted it.

But why would the Nest-builders want to prevent the return of the Shadows? Time travel paradoxes could be an explanation, but sending information back in time is established as a functional technology in universe. See the Exordium project and the sending back of the specs of hell class weapons, conjoiner drives, information about the Melding Plague and the ship building edict. Allowing the digital minds of the Shadows to return wouldn't be different.

Fear that the Shadows would have challenged their dominance is unreasonable considering that they shared their technologie with mankind. Even more mysterious is that they could have gotten rid of the Shadows easily by destroying the Haldora object.

Comment: As far as I can recall it's never explained quite why the Nestbuilders are so opposed to the Shadows entering the local universe via the relay built by the Scuttlers, to the point that they exterminated the Scuttler race to prevent it. Since the exact nature of the Shadows is also left an open question, it's not something I think you'll get a definitive answer on.

Comment: Once again, Reynolds loves to universe build, but seemingly has an intense dislike of actually telling the story he builds up.  It's frustrating, and why I won't read his stuff any more :(

Answer (score 2):

I agree that there was no concrete reason provided, but I don't think the Shadows are strictly "future humans." The Shadows were described as beings from a different "brane" as described in "brane cosmology theory," which apparently is some version of string theory. According to the theory, there are a large (possibly infinite) number of higher dimensions, called branes. As far as I understand it, this is basically the same thing as saying they are extra-dimensional beings. It's possible that they were once human (although I don't recall seeing any indicators that they were human) but even if they were once human, it was not simply time travel that made them a threat (even though time is also a dimension). So maybe the Nestbuilders believed that would be a much greater threat than the Inhibitors or even Greenfly because those at least seemed to be bound to 4-dimensional space like the rest of us.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be a much stronger answer if you could quote specifically where the Shadows are described as not being from our universe, and to highlight that more than the last few sentences, which are fairly speculative.  Please read [answer] for more pointers on a good answer.

Comment: What suggests that the shadows are future humans is that the danger they are fleeing from is described the same way as Greenfly. Some of the short-stories and the end of Absolution Gap also describe Greenfly.